# Bash Scripting user input of filename

Tags: bash, scripting

okay so I am currently working on a bash script for a class that pulls user input for a specific filename. The files are all stored in the same directory so is there anyway to add the path to the users input of the filename?

example:

```
echo -en "Please enter a .log name (/home/me/logs/****.log) : "
read filename
```

where filename is the user input to later be used in a case statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do a string concat to get the required file path. Code example below:

```
echo -en "Please enter a .log name (/home/me/logs/****.log) : "
read filename
filepath="/home/me/logs/$filename.log"
echo $filepath
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to accomplish this

```
cd /home/me/logs
echo -en "print filename"
read fname
abpath="$(pwd)/${fname}"
echo ${abpath}
```